# How to shorten URL with Bitly V4 API and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

So I am trying to shorten an URL with the new V4 Bitly API, but I am getting an JSON error.

My code:

```
$(function() {
    $(".createBitly").on("click", function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        var accessToken = "xxx";

        var params = {
            "long_url" : encodeURIComponent(url)            
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/bitlinks",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            method: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            },
            data: params
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }).fail(function(data) {
            console.error(data);
        });

    });
});
```

Results: a 422 http error;

```
  "{"message":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY","resource":"bitlinks","description":"The JSON value provided is invalid."}"
```

But running it with CURL does work though: [How to shorten URL using PHP Bitly v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55681871/how-to-shorten-url-using-php-bitly-v4)

What am I doing wrong? Is it not possible with jQuery only?

TIA.

Comment: Could it be that the long_url value must be an escaped JS string rather than encoded by applying encodeURIComponent() to it ? The example in the linked case is {"long_url":"https:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/questions\/ask"}. Which would be "https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2Fask" after encoding. I assume Bitly wants to find slashes so as to process the URL. Interestingly the Bitly API docs say the long_url 'must' be uriencoded, but the answer in the example you link to uses json_encode.

Comment: yes it seems you do not send correct json-encoded data

Comment: I also tried escape(), no luck. Also tried  "https:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/questions\/ask" as a string, no luck either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had made this edit from your code above and its working well.

1) `JSON.stringify` before sending request (convert your request to JSON format).

2) No need for `encodeURIComponent()`.

```
$(function() {
  $(".createBitly").on("click", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    var accessToken = "token";

    var params = {
        "long_url" : url           
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        method: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(params)
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);

    }).fail(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
  });
});
```